# VHDL floating point adder - bound check error

Tags: floating-point, vhdl

I'm writing a code for a floating point adder. Here follows my code and the testbench I've used. During the simulation (`ghdl -r fp_add_TB --vcd=add_fp_TB.vcd`) I get the following errors:

```
:error: bound check failure at fp_adder_32_bits_corretto.vhdl:51
in process .fp_add_tb(testbench).dut@fp_add(dataflow).P6
  from: process work.fp_add(dataflow).P6 at fp_adder_32_bits_corretto.vhdl:51
```

Main code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all; 
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY add_fp is
  port(A, B : IN std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
       sum: OUT std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  );  
end entity add_fp;

ARCHITECTURE dataflow OF add_fp IS    
-- extraction to signals of exponent, mantissa, sign
-- single precision: exp = 8 bits, mantissa = 23 bits
  SIGNAL sign_A, sign_B, sign_sum: std_logic;
  SIGNAL frac_A, frac_B: std_logic_vector(22 downto 0);  
  signal exp_A, exp_B: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  
-- sum and difference of the mantissa (fractional) part
-- (with an extra bit for rounding)
  SIGNAL frac_shifted_a, frac_shifted_b, frac_sum: std_logic_vector(23 downto 0); 

  
-- exp differences
  signal exp_diff, exp_fin: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

--carry out
signal carry_out: BIT; 
  
BEGIN
  -- input signals
  sign_A <= A(31);
  sign_B <= B(31);
  exp_A <= A(30 downto 23);
  exp_B <= B(30 downto 23);
  frac_A <= A(22 downto 0);
  frac_B <= B (22 downto 0);




  -- Shift in order to get same exponents


frac_shifted_a <= (others => '0');
frac_shifted_b <= (others => '0');
frac_sum <= (others => '0');


  PROCESS(exp_A, exp_B, frac_A, frac_B)
  begin
    if exp_A < exp_B then
      exp_diff <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_B) - unsigned(exp_A));
      frac_shifted_a <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_A) srl to_integer(unsigned(exp_diff)));
      exp_fin<= exp_B;

    elsif exp_A > exp_B then
      exp_diff <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_A) - unsigned(exp_B));
      frac_shifted_b <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_B) srl to_integer(unsigned(exp_diff)));

      exp_fin <= exp_A;

    end if;
  end process;



  -- sum of the fractional parts

process(frac_shifted_a, frac_shifted_b)
begin

    frac_sum <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_shifted_a) +  unsigned(frac_shifted_b));
end process;


  -- fractional part normalization (carry out bit)
  PROCESS(exp_fin, frac_sum)
  BEGIN
    
 
    carry_out <= '0';
    IF frac_sum(23) = '1' THEN
     frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) sll 1);
      exp_fin <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_fin) + 1);
     carry_out <= '1';
    
   END IF;
  END PROCESS;



  -- Fractional part rounding 
  PROCESS(exp_fin, frac_sum)
  BEGIN
    IF frac_sum(0) = '1' THEN
   frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) + 2);   -- + 10
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;

  -- sign calculation
--here probably I have to consider if A > B or viceversa, but this is not the point of my question
    sign_sum <= sign_A xor sign_B;
 

-- renormalization after the rounding

process(frac_sum, exp_fin)
begin
if carry_out = '0' and frac_sum(23) = '1' then

 frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) sll 1);
      exp_fin <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_fin) + 1);
end if;
end process;


  -- final result
  sum <= sign_sum & exp_fin & frac_sum(23 downto 1);
END architecture dataflow;
```

Test bench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity fp_add_TB is
end entity fp_add_TB;

architecture testbench of fp_add_TB is
  -- Component declaration
  component fp_add is
    port (
      A, B : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      sum : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
  end component fp_add;

  -- Signals
  signal A, B, sum : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin
  -- Instantiate the DUT (Device Under Test)
  DUT : fp_add
    port map (
      A => A,
      B => B,
      sum => sum
    );

  -- Stimulus process
  process
  begin
    -- Test vector 1
    A <= "01000000010000000000000000000000"; -- 3.0
    B <= "01000000001000000000000000000000"; -- 1.5
    wait for 10 ns;

    -- Test vector 2
    A <= "11000000010000000000000000000000"; -- -3.0
    B <= "01000000001000000000000000000000"; -- 1.5
    wait for 10 ns;

    -- Test vector 3
    A <= "00111111100000000000000000000000"; -- 0.5
    B <= "00000000000000000000000000000000"; -- 0.0
    wait for 10 ns;

    -- Add more test vectors as needed
    
    -- Stop simulation
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture testbench;
```

Comment: The DUT in your testbench is fp_add. The entity you provided is add_fp. Is this the same design? Please fix. The line number  51 you provided  in the error message seems to point to a line which is okay. Please check. I found bugs in line 53 (frac_shifted_a <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_A) srl to_integer(unsigned(exp_diff)));) and 58 were the LHS has 24 bit and the RHS has 23 bits.

Comment: There are other issues. exp_diff is evaluated without an intervening wait (including the implicit wait on sensitivity list as a last statement), exp_fin, frac_sum,  is driven from multiple processes, there are signals  evaluated that aren't in sensitivity lists. (A concurrent signal assignment represents a process statement). The lack of matching elements in those two assignments are the least of the issues.

Comment: Neither the question nor the upvoted answer have functional or synthesis eligible code. [This answer process for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKs2S.jpg) uses a while loop (synthesis) and assigns signals without an intervening wait statement (either from the process sensitivity list or explicit wait statements). This should probably be a procedure call. Label processes please. There are multiple processes assigning the same signals which will provide their resolved value, that can't be synthesized in an FPGA.

Comment: `frac_B`  (23 bits) and `frac_shifted_b` (24 bits) have different sizes. You cannot assign `frac_B srl something` to `frac_shifted_b`.

Comment: Also note that comparing `std_logic_vector` objects with the `<` operator when using `ieee.numeric_std` is probably a bad idea. The comparison is not numeric, it is lexicographic. So, for instance, `"011" < "1"`. If your comparisons are always unsigned use, maybe, `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned` instead of `numeric_std` (and save all the conversions to/from `unsigned`).

Comment: Last but not least prefer `std_ulogic` and `std_ulogic_vector` over `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector`. The latter are resolved and in case of accidental multiple drive (assigning the same signal in two or more processes) you do not get any warning or error, while with the former you get clear error messages. This could save you hours of debugging when you will try to understand why the signal value is `X` while you expected something else...

Answer (score 1):

With this changed code the simulation now runs without errors or warnings.

Changes: sensitivity lists, overflow errors with vectors, I've added an extra bit in frac_sum and frac_shifted vectors in order to consider carry out bit, I've changed fp representation from 1.### to 0.### (it was easier for me to implement).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all; 
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY add_fp is
  port(A, B : IN std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
       sum: OUT std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
       cout: out std_logic
  );  
end entity add_fp;

ARCHITECTURE dataflow OF add_fp IS    
-- extraction to signals of exponent, mantissa, sign
-- single precision: exp = 8 bits, mantissa = 23 bits
  SIGNAL sign_A, sign_B, sign_sum: std_logic;
  SIGNAL frac_A, frac_B: std_logic_vector(22 downto 0);  
  signal exp_A, exp_B: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  
-- sum and difference of the mantissa (fractional) part
-- (with an extra bit for rounding)
  SIGNAL frac_shifted_a, frac_shifted_b, frac_sum: std_logic_vector(24 downto 0); 

  
-- exp differences
  signal exp_diff, exp_fin: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

--carry out
signal carry_out: BIT; 
  
BEGIN
  -- input signals
  sign_A <= A(31);
  sign_B <= B(31);
  exp_A <= A(30 downto 23);
  exp_B <= B(30 downto 23);
  frac_A <= A(22 downto 0);
  frac_B <= B (22 downto 0);




  -- Shift in order to get same exponents


frac_shifted_a <= (others => '0');
frac_shifted_b <= (others => '0');
frac_sum <= (others => '0');


  PROCESS (exp_diff, frac_shifted_a, frac_shifted_b, exp_fin)
  begin
    if exp_A < exp_B then
      exp_diff <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_B) - unsigned(exp_A));
      frac_shifted_a <= '0' & std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_A) srl to_integer(unsigned(exp_diff))) & '0'; 
      -- first '0' is the carry out bit, last '0' is for rounding
      exp_fin<= exp_B;

    elsif exp_A > exp_B then
      exp_diff <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_A) - unsigned(exp_B));
      frac_shifted_b <= '0' & std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_B) srl to_integer(unsigned(exp_diff))) & '0';
      exp_fin <= exp_A;

    end if;
  end process;



  -- sum of the fractional parts

process(frac_shifted_a, frac_shifted_b, frac_sum)
begin

    frac_sum <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_shifted_a) +  unsigned(frac_shifted_b));
end process;


-- one fractional part normalization and rounding cycle

process(frac_sum, exp_fin)
begin

if frac_sum(24) = '0' then
frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) sll 1);
      exp_fin <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_fin) - 1);
end if;
  -- Fractional part rounding

    IF frac_sum(0) = '1' THEN
   frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) + 1);
    END IF;
end process;


-- LOOP fractional part normalization using the format 0.###
  
process(frac_sum, exp_fin)
begin
while frac_sum(24) = '0' loop
-- normalize until there's a one at position frac_sum(24)
 frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) sll 1);
      exp_fin <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_fin) - 1);

  -- Fractional part rounding 

    IF frac_sum(0) = '1' THEN
   frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) + 1);  
    END IF;

end loop;
  END PROCESS;

  -- sign calculation
    sign_sum <= sign_A xor sign_B;
 

-- renormalization after the rounding

process(frac_sum, exp_fin)
begin
while frac_sum(24) = '0' loop
-- normalize until there's a one at position frac_sum(24)
 frac_sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(frac_sum) sll 1);
      exp_fin <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(exp_fin) - 1);
end loop;
end process;


  -- final result
  sum <= sign_sum & exp_fin & frac_sum(23 downto 1);
  cout<= frac_sum(24);
END architecture dataflow;
```